# efficient C++ template implementation for 2D range queries

Tags: c++, tree, nearest-neighbor, quadtree

I need to store custom point objects (getX() and getY() are provided) in an efficient way to perform range queries. So i was looking for templated implementations of quadtree, kd-tree or similar. For example like this: https://code.google.com/p/kche-tree/ (but this only seems to work with primitive types...?)

Are there suggestions? Or would i need to implement it myself?
(open source license required)

Thanks!

Comment: `(open source license required)` -> What are your exact requirements? Open Source is not a magic term for free code that you can use for whatever you desire. There are legal restrictions, and they depend on the specific license.

Comment: @phresnel: MIT or GPL are fine (preferably in that order)

Comment: Are you planning on publishing your application? If so, as GPL licensed?

Comment: @phresnel: yes, i plan to publish it. the license will depend on the license of the used tree-library: if its MIT, i would go for MIT or GPL. if it's GPL, i cannot go for MIT any more. but  apart from that, both are fine with me.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I was asking because depending on this, different answers are valid :)

Comment: @downvoter: please explain your downvote such that i can learn.

Comment: Strange, I received a notification, even though you addressed `@downvoter`. (note I did not downvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **use boost**. Boost are usually pretty good C++ libraries.

And [Boost Geometry](http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry) has and R-tree for nearest neighbor search.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://compilr.com/cobalthex/quadtree/main.cpp
It's also what I am looking for. I guess the code is opensource and you are able to reuse and modify it.

All you need is the Quadtree.h and Quadtree.cpp. Modify the XY point to the struct that you see suitable for your usage.

Hope this helps!